# Не работает свойство justify-content: space-between;

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

```
            Всем добрый вечер :-)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не работает свойство justify-content: space-between; в данном конкретном примере. https://yadi.sk/d/dQk3b0Vx5lpbTw  Ведь оно как я понял
прижимает элементы контейнера к краям а между ними оставляет равный промежуток. Но на самом деле получается так :-(   https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvXdE.png  Помогите пожалуйста понять где ошибка.  С  уважением Сергей Кондулуков

Comment: выложите код сюда, т.к. картинки могут пропасть из ресурса, куда вы выложили и тогда, через пару лет (месяцев/дней/часов) ваш ответ потеряет смысл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете тег `<menu>`, у которого есть стили по умолчанию, среди которых внутренний левый отступ `padding`.

Flexbox отрабатывает нормально, прижимая крайний левый элемент к левому краю. Просто у Вас левый край смещен.

Задайте тегу принудительно `padding: 0`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: hisbvdis Спасибо вам большое :-)  Я задал тегу menu padding: 15px; чтобы были отступы и слева и справа. Смотрите, что получилось https://i.imgur.com/WupQ3zS.png.  С уважением и благодарностью  Сергей.